# Windows no carga pero Linux si

Tags: windows, centos

Buenos días sucede que intento arreglar una pc que en un principio no cargaba el sistema operativo por lo cual pensé que era un error del disco duro. 
Conseguí  otro  disco  duro (Particionado para windows 7 starter y Centos 6.5) y lo probé  en otra compu  todo funciona de maravilla en ambos  sistemas.

Posteriormente lo conecte a la pc que no funcionaba  y carga perfectamente Centos pero no carga  windows, se queda en el logo y se vuelve a iniciar. Ya verifique que los requisitos minimos de windows se cumplan y ya  reinstale  windows desde 0, corri las herramientas de recuperación y  tampoco funciono, ¿alguna sugerencia ?
De ante mano gracias